# How do I return the sum of array with exceptions by using a while loop in a function?

Tags: while-loop

Python beginner here.
I already have the solution to the question but I'm not understanding why the "add" variable in the solution plays a role of creating exceptions to remove numbers between 6 and 9. I already tried Python Tutor but still not understanding. Many thanks in advance!

**QUESTION: Return the sum of the numbers in the array, except ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and extending to the next 9 (every 6 will be followed by at least one 9). Return 0 for no numbers.**

**Sample Solution code**

```
def summer_69(arr):
    total = 0
    add = True
    
    for num in arr:
        while add:
            if num != 6:
                total += num
                break
            else:
                add = False
        while not add:
            if num != 9:
                break
            else:
                add = True
                break
    return total
```

**Sample answers:**

```
summer_69([1, 3, 5]) --> 9
summer_69([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) --> 9
summer_69([2, 1, 6, 9, 11]) --> 14
```

Comment: All your samples run successfully. What kind of exceptions and what inputs you are talking about? Could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of the variable "add" as a flag. I think that might be a better name for this variable in this instance.

It is only being used to tell if you have run into a 6 within the sequence of numbers in the array, then once it has been set it goes through an arbitrary amount of numbers in the array until it gets a 9 and then it resets the flag.

It may help to rename the variable "add" as "flag". Have your new variable "flag" default to False and then if you run into a 6 set "flag" to true. Once the flag is on do not add any trailing numbers in the sequence until you run into the number 9 then reset to false.

Perhaps that will help the readability. Naming variables is the hardest part of programming.

Comment: @keab28 No problem!